# How would I model a CQL table to be able to retrieve timeseries data by range of days?

Tags: cassandra

I have different locations where mobile measurements of temperature are made at random times (not periodically). The unique identifier of the measurement is it's location together with the time of measurement (two measurements on the same location and at the same time are not possible). I need to find all the measurements on particular location, that were recorded in a particular part of the year (something like "spring measurements", "summer measurements"...). For example I might want to get all the measurements recorded from 2nd to 25th January, **regardless of the year** of the measurement (NOTE: I do not want the measurements from 2nd to 25th January of particular year - but for all the years during which the measurements were taken!).

I have come up with a data model/table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE meas (
    latitude double,
    longitude double,
    measurementTime timestamp,
    dayOfYear int,
    value double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((latitude, longitude), measurementTime, dayOfYear)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (measurementTime DESC, dayOfYear DESC)
```

I would like to query:
Give me all the rows where latitude=XXX and longitude=YYY and dayOfYear >= ZZZ and dayOfYear <= WWW

So an example query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM meas WHERE latitude=46.1 AND longitude=15.1 AND dayOfYear >= 2 AND dayOfYear <= 25;
```

The problem I am facing is that this query involves filtering (since I am not providing the value of the measurementTime) - therefore I need to specify ALLOW FILTERING in the query. However I would like to avoid filtering (to make query more efficient). Any ideas how the data model would look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query by day of year then you should model your table accordingly:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_by_location_dayofyear (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ((latitude, longitude), dayOfYear)
```

But the "day-of-the-year" is not a unique clustering key because each year has such day. You're better off with a year AND a day as clustering keys:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_by_location_dayofyear (
    latitude double,
    longitude double,
    year int,
    dayofyear int,
    measurementtime timestamp,
    value double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((latitude, longitude), year, dayofyear)
```

You would then be able to query the table with:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_by_location_dayofyear
WHERE latitude = ?
  AND longitude = ?
  AND year = ?
  AND dayofyear >= ?
  AND dayofyear <= ?
```

But strictly speaking using the day of the year is unnecessary. You were right in the first place to use the measurement time as the clustering key -- you just need to restrict the query based on the timestamp.

Here's the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_by_location (
    latitude double,
    longitude double,
    measurementtime timestamp,
    value double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((latitude, longitude), measurementtime)
```

and you would query the table with:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_by_location_dayofyear
WHERE latitude = ?
  AND longitude = ?
  AND measurementtime >= '2022-01-02 +0000'
  AND dayofyear <= '2022-01-25 +0000'
```

Remember that the CQL `timestamp` type is [encoded as the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html) so you can extract the date from it. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick, thank you for your reply however it does not help - maybe I was not specific enough in my question - I do not want to specify the year - I want the measurements from e.g. 2nd to 25th January for all the years during which the measurements were recorded (as said - query should support something like "give me all the spring measurements", or "all summer measurements" - except that the "time window" is dynamic in my case (kind of sliding window) - so I cannot categorize measurements in "spring", "summer" etc...).

Comment: What you want is not OLTP -- it's an analytics query. As such, you should instead use Spark to query your tables with the spark-cassandra-connector since it is optimised for analytics workloads. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I will consider using Spark if it turns out that the query with ALLOW FILTERING becomes too slow...